# categorizing raw folder in android?

Tags: android, resources, audio

I have around 300 .mp3 files. so i need to place it in raw folder. Is there any way to keep these files in a group (like animalvoice, birdsvoice etc) ?

I try to add a folder inside the raw folder to group 100 sound files in each folder. But  resource id is not generating..

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

this is simply not possible.

if you you want to folder structure Assets is the way to go, but then you have to do your own path management.